# Splitting an HTML document into many HTML docs automatically

Tags: jquery, html, xml, automation

I have a webpage that contains [content for 260 news articles](http://fowlertown.com/projects/coe/newsyear.html). I need each article in a separate HTML file. Instead of copy and pasting each of these blocks of content (which I've pre-formatted using jQuery for copy/pasting - it was originally an XML file) manually into new files, is there a way I can automate this? Please someone tell me there's a way.

Comment: You need to look into file objects

Answer (score 0):

Should be something that you can cook-up fairly easily with just about any scripting language.  It looks like each new article begins with "---\nTitle".  So, it would just be a matter of reading the source file line-by-line, opening a new output file whenever you encounter "---\nTitle", and writing the lines out to the current output file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it started as XML, then you can split it very easily using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="article">
  <xsl:result-document href="article{position()}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

where the match pattern is whatever characterizes the elements that mark your article boundaries. Much better to do this using the XML structure that to convert it into plain text and then manipulate that.